# Some hack to set the monotonic clock in C++ / Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

Linux C++ question, they say you can't set the monotonic clock. I want to set the monotonic clock. Is there some hack or trick to do this from C++ in Linux? I want to use clock_settime(CLOCK_MONOTONC, &ts) and have it set the clock to the time specified in ts, or some othe rmethod other than clock_settime to accomplish the same thing? I'm cool with elaborate hacks or workarounds.

Comment: "CLOCK_MONOTONIC: A **nonsettable** system-wide clock ..... The CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock is not affected by discontinuous
              jumps in the system time but is affected by the incremental adjustments performed by **adjtime(3)** ..." Links: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_settime.2.html and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/adjtime.3.html

Comment: A settable clock would no longer be monotonic, and would break all of the software that relied on the clock's documented guarantee of monotonicity.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve that gives rise to this quesiton?

Answer (score 3):

1. Read it.
2. Subtract the current value from the value you wish it was.
3. In the future, add this offset.

Answer (score 0):

Interpose both `clock_gettime()` and `clock_settime()` with your own.

Here is a tested working example, that should be thread-safe.  First, the **libmonotonic.c** itself:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef  ENV_OFFSET_NAME
#define  ENV_OFFSET_NAME  "LIBMONOTONIC_OFFSET"
#endif

typedef int (*clock_gettime_funcptr)(clockid_t, struct timespec *);
typedef int (*clock_settime_funcptr)(clockid_t, const struct timespec *);

static volatile clock_gettime_funcptr  original_clock_gettime = NULL;
static volatile clock_settime_funcptr  original_clock_settime = NULL;

static volatile long  offset_sec  = 0;
static volatile long  offset_nsec = 0;

/* Call original clock_gettime(). */
static inline int do_clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp)
{
    clock_gettime_funcptr  original = __atomic_load_n(&original_clock_gettime, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    if (!original) {
        original = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "clock_gettime");
        if (!original) {
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return original(clk_id, tp);
}

/* Call original clock_settime(). */
static inline int do_clock_settime(clockid_t clk_id, const struct timespec *tp)
{
    clock_settime_funcptr  original = __atomic_load_n(&original_clock_settime, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    if (!original) {
        original = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "clock_settime");
        if (!original) {
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return original(clk_id, tp);
}

/* Interposed version of clock_settime(). */
int clock_settime(clockid_t clk_id, const struct timespec *tp)
{
    if (clk_id != CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
        return do_clock_settime(clk_id, tp);

    struct timespec  now;

    if (do_clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now) == -1)
        return -1;

    long  off_sec  = tp->tv_sec  - now.tv_sec;
    long  off_nsec = tp->tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec;

    if (off_nsec <= -1000000000) {
        off_sec -=   (-off_nsec) / 1000000000;
        off_nsec = -((-off_nsec) % 1000000000);
    }
    if (off_nsec >= 1000000000) {
        off_sec += off_nsec / 1000000000;
        off_nsec = off_nsec % 1000000000;
    }

    do {
        __atomic_store_n(&offset_sec,  off_sec,  __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
        __atomic_store_n(&offset_nsec, off_nsec, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    } while (offset_sec != off_sec || offset_nsec != off_nsec);

    return 0;
}

int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp)
{
    if (clk_id != CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
        return do_clock_gettime(clk_id, tp);

    struct timespec  now;
    long             off_sec, off_nsec;

    if (do_clock_gettime(clk_id, &now) == -1)
        return -1;

    do {
        off_sec  = __atomic_load_n(&offset_sec,  __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
        off_nsec = __atomic_load_n(&offset_nsec, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    } while (off_sec != offset_sec || off_nsec != offset_nsec);

    now.tv_sec  += off_sec;
    now.tv_nsec += off_nsec;

    if (now.tv_nsec < 0) {
        const long  nsec = -now.tv_nsec;
        now.tv_sec -= 1 + nsec / 1000000000;
        now.tv_nsec = 1000000000 - (nsec % 1000000000);
    }
    if (now.tv_nsec >= 1000000000) {
        now.tv_sec += now.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
        now.tv_nsec = now.tv_nsec % 1000000000;
    }

    *tp = now;
    return 0;
}

static void monotonic_init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void monotonic_init(void)
{
    const int   saved_errno = errno;
    const char *value = getenv(ENV_OFFSET_NAME);

    if (value && *value)
        do {
            long  off_sec = 0, off_nsec = 0;
            long  decimal = 100000000;
            int   negative = 0;

            /* Skip leading whitespace. */
            while (*value == '\t' || *value == '\n' || *value == '\v' ||
                   *value == '\f' || *value == '\r' || *value == ' ')
                value++;

            /* Parse signs. */
            while (*value == '+' || *value == '-')
                if (*(value++) == '-')
                    negative = !negative;

            /* Require first digit. */
            if (*value >= '0' && *value <= '9')
                off_sec = (*(value++) - '0');
            else
                break;

            /* Parse the rest of the integer digits. */
            while (*value >= '0' && *value <= '9')
                off_sec = (10 * off_sec) + (*(value++) - '0');

            /* Fractional part? */
            if (*value == '.') {
                value++;

                while (*value >= '0' && *value <= '9') {
                    if (decimal > 0) {
                        off_nsec += decimal * (long)((*value) - '0');
                        decimal /= 10;
                    }
                    value++;
                }
            }

            /* Skip trailing whitespace. */
            while (*value == '\t' || *value == '\n' || *value == '\v' ||
                   *value == '\f' || *value == '\r' || *value == ' ')
                value++;

            /* Garbage? */
            if (*value)
                break;

            /* Negative? */
            if (negative) {
                off_sec  = -off_sec;
                off_nsec = -off_nsec;
            }

            /* Store. */
            do {
                __atomic_store_n(&offset_sec,  off_sec,  __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
                __atomic_store_n(&offset_nsec, off_nsec, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
            } while (offset_sec != off_sec || offset_nsec != off_nsec);

       } while (0);

    errno = saved_errno;
}
```

The `monotonic_init()` function gets executed whenever the library is loaded. (If used in `LD_PRELOAD`, it is executed before `main()`.)  If the `LIBMONOTONIC_OFFSET` is set, it is used as the initial offset to CLOCK_MONOTONIC.

For testing (getting the monotonic clock), here's a simple example test program, **monotonic.c**:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec now;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get monotonic clock: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%ld.%09ld\n", (long)now.tv_sec, now.tv_nsec);

    /* Set clock to zero. */
    now.tv_sec = 0;
    now.tv_nsec = 0;
    if (clock_settime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set monotonic clock: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Monotonic clock was set to %ld.%09ld successfully.\n", (long)now.tv_sec, now.tv_nsec);

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get monotonic clock: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%ld.%09ld\n", (long)now.tv_sec, now.tv_nsec);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that this program is not linked against libmonotonic.so in any way.

Finally, here is the **Makefile** to help compile all these:

```make
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -Wextra -O2
LDFLAGS := -ldl
TARGETS := libmonotonic.so monotonic

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGETS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

%.so: %.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

monotonic: monotonic.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Note that because this forum eats <kbd>Tab</kbd>s, you need to fix the indentation of **Makefile** after creating it, by running `sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile`.

Run `make clean all` to build both the library and the example program.  Then, run e.g.

```
./monotonic
env LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libmonotonic.so LIBMONOTONIC_OFFSET=-5321.2345 ./monotonic
./monotonic
```

On my system, the output happens to be

```
1139233.519719376
Cannot set monotonic clock: Invalid argument.

1133912.791484465
Monotonic clock was set to 0.000000000 successfully.
0.000007698

1139234.531043242
Cannot set monotonic clock: Invalid argument.
```

Note the -5321 difference between the first and the second number: this is the effect of the `LIBMONOTONIC_OFFSET` environment variable, when libmonotonic.so is loaded.

Also, when libmonotonic.so is loaded, the clock_settime() call succeeds.

Note that if the binary uses CLOCK_MONOTONIC based TIMER_ABSTIME timers (via `timer_create()`, `timer_settime()` etc.), one should also interpose `timer_create()` and `timer_delete()` to remember which timers are based on CLOCK_MONOTONIC, and `timer_settime()` to adjust the initial time when TIMER_ABSTIME is set in the flags.  (`timer_gettime()` always returns relative values, so it does not need to be interposed; and relative timers do not need any adjustments anyway.)

Answer (score -1):

Check out [std::chrono::steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock)